# How do i get specific columns from datatables to fill a constructor with?

Tags: vb.net

I got 2 DataTables which i open with a openFileDialog with the following columnnames: "UANR", "KostenArt", "Ueberbegriff", "Benennung", "Anzahl", "Einheit", "Einzelkosten", "SummenCode", "Kst", "AufPos", "Summenkosten".

But i only need the values for the following ones,

```
ReadOnly Property KostenArt As String
ReadOnly Property UANR As String
ReadOnly Property Ueberbegriff As String
ReadOnly Property Benennung As String
ReadOnly Property Anzahl As Double
ReadOnly Property Einheit As String
ReadOnly Property Einzelkosten As Double
ReadOnly Property Gesamtmenge As Integer
ReadOnly Property Summencode As String
```

to fill the constructor with and make a list of objects with this method:

```
Private Function ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt As DataTable, lst As List(Of ISAACService)) As List(Of ISAACService)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim ISAAC As New ISAACService(row(KostenArt).ToString, row(UANR).ToString, row(Ueberbegriff).ToString, row(Benennung).ToString, CDbl(row(Anzahl)), row(Einheit).ToString, CDbl(row(Einzelkosten)), CInt(row(Gesamtmenge)), row(Summencode).ToString)
        lst.Add(ISAAC)
    Next

    Return lst
End Function
```

Here is how i put in the datatables:

```
Private Sub btnDatei1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDatei1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If File.Exists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then
            dt1 = FileGenerator.ReadFromProtectedFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            dgv1.DataSource = dt1
            ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt1, lst1)

        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnDatei2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDatei2.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        dt2 = FileGenerator.ReadFromProtectedFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        dgv2.DataSource = dt2
        ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt2, lst2)
    End If
End Sub
```

The full code:

```
Public Class MainForm

Private Const KostenArt As String = "KostenArt"
Private Const UANR As String = "UANR"
Private Const Ueberbegriff As String = "Ueberbegriff"
Private Const Benennung As String = "Benennung"
Private Const Anzahl As String = "Anzahl"
Private Const Einheit As String = "Einheit"
Private Const Einzelkosten As String = "Einzelkosten"
Private Const Gesamtmenge As String = "Gesamtmenge"
Private Const Summencode As String = "Summencode"

Public dt1, dt2 As DataTable
Public lst1, lst2 As List(Of ISAACService)

Private Sub btnDatei1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDatei1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If File.Exists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then
            dt1 = FileGenerator.ReadFromProtectedFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            dgv1.DataSource = dt1
            ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt1, lst1)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnVergleich_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVergleich.Click

    'CompareDataTables()




End Sub




Private Sub btnDatei2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDatei2.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        dt2 = FileGenerator.ReadFromProtectedFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        dgv2.DataSource = dt2
        ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt2, lst2)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CompareDataTables(ByRef lst1 As List(Of ISAACService), ByRef lst2 As List(Of ISAACService))



End Sub

Private Function ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt As DataTable, lst As List(Of ISAACService)) As List(Of ISAACService)

    Try
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

            Dim ISAAC As New ISAACService(row(KostenArt).ToString, row(UANR).ToString, row(Ueberbegriff).ToString, row(Benennung).ToString, CDbl(row(Anzahl)), row(Einheit).ToString, CDbl(row(Einzelkosten)), CInt(row(Gesamtmenge)), row(Summencode).ToString)
            lst.Add(ISAAC)
        Next

        Return lst
    Catch ex As System.ArgumentException

    End Try

End Function
```

End Class

Comment: What is not working with the code you have?

Comment: @Magnus The problem is that the return value of the list in ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt1, lst1) is nothing. Also when i call the ConvertDataTableToLIstOfISAACService()-Function i get a System.ArgumentException that says "Column 'KostenArt' doesn't belong to the table"

Comment: where do you fill the datatable? what are the contents?

Comment: @MorenajeRD I'm not quite sure what you mean, the contents are the properties i mentioned in my post and i fill the datatables in the button click events

Comment: what is  --- FileGenerator.ReadFromProtectedFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) ---  returning ?

Comment: @MorenajeRD it decrypts the file and returns a datatable with the colum names i mentioned in my post

Comment: Where is lst1 declared? Show the code. I assume that those properties are from the ISAACService. I assume that there is a parameterized constructor.

Comment: @Mary i updated the post with the full code from mainform.vb. The Properties are from ISAACServiceBase which inherits to ISAACService

Comment: You have declared lst1 as a type but I don't see where you have ever instantiated an instance.

Comment: Debug the code, look at the Datatable columns in the debugger and see if the columns match what you think they should be.

Answer (score 1):

Think the problem is in the way you've declared lst and the signature of the ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService method.  Try something like this maybe.

```
Private Function ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt As DataTable) As List(Of ISAACService)
    Dim lst As Zew List(Of ISAACService)
    Try
           For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
           Dim ISAAC As New ISAACService(row(KostenArt).ToString, row(UANR).ToString, row(Ueberbegriff).ToString, row(Benennung).ToString, CDbl(row(Anzahl)), row(Einheit).ToString, CDbl(row(Einzelkosten)), CInt(row(Gesamtmenge)), row(Summencode).ToString)
           lst.Add(ISAAC)
        Next

        Return lst
   Catch ex As System.ArgumentException
       'Do something with the exception, here.
   End Try

End Function
```

It's also more than possible something is throwing an exception, but with your empty catch block, it's not being reported

Comment: If i don't throw the exception it says: "Column 'KostenArt' doesn't belong to the table". Do you have any idea whats that all about? It worked just fine but at some point it stopped working and i dont know why.

Comment: Well that would get back to dt1 = FileGenerator.ReadFromProtectedFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)  I would think that is not doing what you think it should be doing.  You might be better off creating a new question with the focus on that method